# rotating cubes differently

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I have 25 cubes that i want to rotate each one differently this is my code on both x and y axis

i tried using rand() but it kept rotating them weirdly and all of them rotate in the same directions

this is in the game loop

```cpp
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
{
    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    model = glm::translate(model, cubePositions[i]);
    view = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f));
    float angle = 20.0f * i;

    angle = glfwGetTime() * 20.0f;

    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(angle), glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f));
    GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "model");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));
    GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "view");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));
    GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "projection");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, 
    glm::value_ptr(projection));

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
}
```

Comment: *" i want to rotate each one differently"* - so you need a rotation axis and angle for each cube. I suggest an array of 25 axis and angles.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to help you, we need a clear question. So please clarify and be precise on what you want and tried already (and where it failed).

Comment: can you explain it more in details?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no actual question, I try to give some comments on the posted code
that could explain the unexpected behavior of the resulting program.

1. The `angle` variable is initialised, then assigned immediately with a new
   value ; only this new value is relevant, then the cubes should all rotate
   at the rate of  20 degrees per second. (this is not a problem)
2. The `view` matrix is reassigned with a new value for **each** object! It is
   extremely unlikely that this is what you want.
   It's like if, while drawing a single frame, you move the camera in front of
   each object being drawn ; if you move the camera and the object the same way,
   then everything is displayed at the same place in the rendered frame.
   (I think this is the main problem)
   You should choose once for all the `view` matrix (as well as the `projection`
   matrix) for the whole frame.

Some other comments, not directly related:

- You should retrieve the uniform locations once for all before the loop
  (and even at the beginning of the program) since they won't change as long
  as you use the same shader program.
- The `glUniformMatrix4fv()` calls for `projection` and `view` should
  occur once for all before the loop; only the `model` matrix changes from
  one object to another.

That could look like this

```
  GLint modelLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "model");
  GLint viewLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "view");
  GLint projLoc = glGetUniformLocation(ourShader.Program, "projection");

  glm::mat4 projection = ... already known ...
  glUniformMatrix4fv(projLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));

  glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f);
  // adjust to the layout of your scene
  view = glm::translate(view, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -10.0f));
  glUniformMatrix4fv(viewLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(view));

  for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
  {
    glm::mat4 model = glm::mat4(1.0f);
    model = glm::translate(model, cubePositions[i]);

    // the same rotation rate but a different offset for each object
    float angle = 20.0f * i;
    angle += std::fmod(glfwGetTime() * 20.0f, 360.0f);
    // choose x or y rotation axis
    auto axis=(i%2) ? glm::vec3(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) : glm::vec3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    model = glm::rotate(model, glm::radians(angle), axis);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelLoc, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
  }
```

Comment: the view matrix should be in the origin and show all the cubes rotating but the problem i want to fix that i want each cube to rotate differently from each other on the x and y axis but im not sure how can i do it i think it has to do with the angle of rotation but i dont know how to change it for each cube

Comment: @l- I just added the choice of a rotation axis depending on the object index.